# No module named 'CLIP'

Tags: clip

I want to use simplified cc 12M
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Tw_gOowjYuWMuX122rrXTd-RV3A8u_ZD?usp=sharing#scrollTo=f_6OhF85i5vp

but I got "No module named 'CLIP" error, I tried to instll CLIP, but it still didn't work.

See the attachment.

How can I solve this problem?thanks.[image]